# Issue with function execution on page load

Tags: function, asynchronous, promise, fetch, loading

I have a small problem with the project from FrondEnd Mentor that I have just completed.
I have a function that is getting data from json file, however as the page initially loads the function fails to execute. Function executes normally when it's being triggered by click event listener (you can do it by clicking one of the switchItems).

```
const activityNames = document.querySelectorAll('.activity-name')
const switchItems = document.querySelectorAll('.switch-item')
const daily = document.querySelector('#daily')
const weekly = document.querySelector('#weekly')
const monthly = document.querySelector('#monthly')

let finalData = {}
let dataRange = 'daily'

loadData()

async function getData() {
    const response = await fetch('data.json')
    const data = await response.json()
    finalData = data
    console.log(finalData)
}

async function loadData() {
    getData()
    const acitivityTimesCurrent = document.querySelectorAll('.activity-time-current')
    const activityTimesPrevious = document.querySelectorAll('.activity-time-previous')

    if (dataRange === 'daily') {
        acitivityTimesCurrent.forEach(function (activity, index) {
            const currentDaily = finalData[index].timeframes.daily.current
            activity.textContent = currentDaily === 1 ? finalData[index].timeframes.daily.current + 'hr' : finalData[index].timeframes.daily.current + 'hrs'

        })
        activityTimesPrevious.forEach(function (activity, index) {
            const previousDaily = finalData[index].timeframes.daily.previous
            activity.textContent = previousDaily === 1 ? 'Yesterday - ' + finalData[index].timeframes.daily.previous + 'hr' : 'Yesterday - ' + finalData[index].timeframes.daily.previous + 'hrs'
        })
    }
    else if (dataRange === 'weekly') {
        acitivityTimesCurrent.forEach(function (activity, index) {
            const currentWeekly = finalData[index].timeframes.weekly.current
            activity.textContent = currentWeekly === 1 ? finalData[index].timeframes.weekly.current + 'hr' : finalData[index].timeframes.weekly.current + 'hrs'

        })
        activityTimesPrevious.forEach(function (activity, index) {
            const previousWeekly = finalData[index].timeframes.weekly.previous
            activity.textContent = previousWeekly === 1 ? 'Last week - ' + finalData[index].timeframes.weekly.previous + 'hr' : 'Last week - ' + finalData[index].timeframes.weekly.previous + 'hrs'
        })
    }
    else {
        acitivityTimesCurrent.forEach(function (activity, index) {
            const currentMonthly = finalData[index].timeframes.monthly.current
            activity.textContent = currentMonthly === 1 ? finalData[index].timeframes.monthly.current + 'hr' : finalData[index].timeframes.monthly.current + 'hrs'

        })
        activityTimesPrevious.forEach(function (activity, index) {
            const previousMonthly = finalData[index].timeframes.monthly.previous
            activity.textContent = previousMonthly === 1 ? 'Last month - ' + finalData[index].timeframes.monthly.previous + 'hr' : 'Last month - ' + finalData[index].timeframes.monthly.previous + 'hrs'
        })
    }

}

switchItems.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        deleteActive()
        dataRange = e.target.dataset.value
        item.classList.add('active')
        loadData()
    })
})

function deleteActive() {
    const switchItems = document.querySelectorAll('.switch-item')
    switchItems.forEach(item => {
        item.classList.remove('active')
    })
}
```

I cannot really find what's causing the issue on the page load and I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'timeframes')
    at script.js:26:51
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at loadData (script.js:25:31)
    at script.js:10:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of your methods are awaited

In the first page load, you should await

```js
await loadData()
```

Most importantly though, the call to `getData` inside `loadData` is your main problem. `getData` is responsible for assigning `finalData`. Since you're not awaiting, it's treated as a "fire & forget" - and most likely not instantiated by the time you reference it.

Again, waiting this function should fix any race conditions you're hitting

```js
async function loadData() {
    await getData();
    // rest of the code here
}
```

Comment: That's so simple, but I haven't thought about it, thank you!

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, be sure to mark as best answer for future viewers